# if (element.textContent.trim() === 'Tea') Does not exist?

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with some code and I'm almost there but i can't figure out this one last thing.

I'm using document.getElementsBy to look for a word in an Iframe, and it works.
But when it finds the word it goes on to another Function.

I want it to send an Alert("not found") if it does not find the word.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var iframe2 = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  const allElements = iframe2.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (const element of allElements) {
    console.log(element);
    if (element.textContent.trim() === 'Tea') {
      alert(element.textContent.trim());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you considered indenting your code to make it readable? - besides that, you can see the string logged as the content of one of the `li` logged?

Comment: perhaps you could `console.log(element.textContent)` instead and see if any of the `li` have that content

Answer (score 0):

You could just store whether you found 'Tea' in a boolean.

That would look something like this:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var iframe2 = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  const allElements = iframe2.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  let foundTea
  for (const element of allElements) {
    if (element.textContent.trim() === 'Tea') {
        found = true
      alert('Tea');
    }
  }
  if (!foundTea) {alert('Not found')}
}
```